Access token handling in Next.js
I am trying to implement an authentication system in my project
Frontend is using Next.js and I have a node server on the backend
but I cannot understand how I can implement a session for the user using access and refresh tokens.
I implemented the login but cannot save the authentication state and the refresh token endpoint is being accessed multiple times. which is also invalidating my refresh token
I am using a useEffect hook to check for the authentication state but it is calling the endpoint twice which is mismatching the tokens in frontend and backend.
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import LoadingSpinner from "@components/LoadingSpinner";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
  });

  const router = useRouter();

  // Log in function
  const login = async (credentials) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRAVYN_API_BASE_URL + "/restaurants/login",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
        credentials: "include",
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorData = await response.json();
      console.error("Error Response:", errorData);
      throw new Error("Login failed: " + errorData.message);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    const { restaurant } = data.data;
    setAuth({ isAuthenticated: true, loading: false, user: restaurant });

    return data;
  };

  // Log out function
  const logout = async (shouldRedirect = true) => {
    try {
      await fetch(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRAVYN_API_BASE_URL + "/restaurants/logout",
        {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Logout failed", error);
    }

    // Reset authentication state
    setAuth({ isAuthenticated: false, loading: false, user: null });

    // Redirect only if shouldRedirect is true
    if (shouldRedirect) {
      router.push("/restaurant/login");
    }
  };

  // Check login status on initial load
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth.isAuthenticated && auth.loading) refreshToken();
    console.log(auth.user);
  }, []);

  const refreshToken = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRAVYN_API_BASE_URL +
          "/restaurants/refresh-token",
        {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();

      console.log(data);

      if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Token verification failed: ", data);

      setAuth({
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
        user: data.data.restaurant,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      logout(true); // Logout without redirect
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, login, logout }}>
      {auth.loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);


here is my Layout.jsx for the restaurant routes
"use client";

import Sidebar from "@components/restaurant/Sidebar";
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "@providers/RestaurantAuthProvider";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function RestaurantLayout({ children }) {
  const path = usePathname();

  const resetLayoutRoutes = ["/restaurant/register", "/restaurant/login"];

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      {resetLayoutRoutes.includes(path) ? (
        <main>{children}</main>
      ) : (
        <main className="wrapper lg:grid grid-cols-[1fr_3fr] relative gap-4">
          <Sidebar />
          {children}
        </main>
      )}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}


here is my login page
"use client";

import { useAuth } from "@providers/RestaurantAuthProvider";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const RestaurantLoginPage = () => {
  const { login, auth } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      router.push("/restaurant/catalog"); // Redirect if already authenticated
    }
  }, [auth, router]);

  const [registrationNumber, setRegistrationNumber] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);

  const { mutate, isPending, isError, error, isSuccess, data } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (formData) => login(formData),
    onSuccess: async (data) => {},

    onError: (error) => {
      console.error("Login failed:", error);
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const restaurant = {
      registrationNumber,
      password,
    };

    mutate(restaurant);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-svh bg-gradient-to-br to-primary-green from-accent-yellow-light overflow-hidden"> 
//................ other things.........

<form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          className="p-8 xl:w-1/2 w-full flex flex-col justify-center bg-white rounded-md"
        >
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4 text-center">Login</h2>

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              htmlFor="phone"
              className="block font-medium text-lg text-gray-700"
            >
              Registration Number
            </label>
            <div className="flex mt-1">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="email"
                className="border-2 border-gray-300 bo p-2 rounded-md w-full  placeholder-shown:invalid:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none  invalid:border-red-400 valid:border-green-500"
                placeholder="Enter Registration Number"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setRegistrationNumber(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-6">
            <label
              htmlFor="password"
              className="block font-medium text-lg text-gray-700"
            >
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              minLength={6}
              maxLength={20}
              className="border-2 border-gray-300 bo p-2 rounded-md w-full placeholder-shown:invalid:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none  invalid:border-red-400 valid:border-green-500"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <input
            type="submit"
            value={isPending ? "Logging in" : "Login"}
            className={`cursor-pointer w-full ${
              isPending ? "bg-accent-yellow" : "bg-primary-green"
            } text-white py-2 rounded-md font-semibold transition duration-300 hover:${
              isPending ? "bg-primary-orange" : "bg-teal-800"
            }`}
          />
          <div className="text-center text-primary-red py-2 h-5 w-max">
            {isError && error.message}
          </div>
          <Link
            href="#"
            className="w-max py-4 font-bold text-primary-green hover:scale-105 hover:font-extrabold transition-all"
          >
            Forgot Password?
          </Link>
          <Link
            href="#"
            className="w-max py-4 font-bold text-primary-green hover:scale-105 hover:font-extrabold transition-all"
          >
            Need Help?
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantLoginPage;

I tried using sessionStorage to store the user but same problems. How can I use the accessToken to keep the user logged in and refresh the session as intended when the accessToken expires.
here are my backend functions for login and refresh token.
This login function sets the httpOnly cookies
restaurant.controller.js

const loginRestaurant = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { registrationNumber, password } = req.body;

  const requiredFields = [
    {
      field: registrationNumber,
      message: "Registration number is required.",
      reason: "Registration number is not defined",
    },
    {
      field: password,
      message: "Password is required.",
      reason: "Password is not defined",
    },
  ];

  for (const { field, message, reason } of requiredFields) {
    if (!field) {
      return res.status(400).json(new ApiResponse({ reason }, message));
    }
  }

  let restaurant =
    await getNonSensitiveRestaurantInfoByRegNo(registrationNumber);

  if (restaurant.length <= 0) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json(
        new ApiResponse(
          { reason: "No restaurant found with given credentials" },
          "Restaurant is not registered."
        )
      );
  }

  restaurant = await getRestaurantById(restaurant[0].restaurant_id);

  if (restaurant.length <= 0) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json(
        new ApiResponse(
          { reason: "No restaurant found with given credentials" },
          "Restaurant is not registered."
        )
      );
  }
  const correctPassword = restaurant[0].password;

  const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, correctPassword);

  if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json(
        new ApiResponse(
          { reason: "Incorrect Password." },
          "Invalid credentials, please try again."
        )
      );
  }
  const accessToken = generateAccessToken(restaurant[0]);
  const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(restaurant[0]);

  const restaurantId = restaurant[0].restaurant_id;

  restaurant = await setRefreshToken(refreshToken, restaurantId);

  const options = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
  };
  delete restaurant[0].refresh_token;
  delete restaurant[0].password;

  return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
    .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, options)
    .json(
      new ApiResponse(
        {
          restaurant: restaurant[0],
          accessToken,
          refreshToken,
        },
        "User logged in successfully."
      )
    );
});

const refreshAccessToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const incomingRefreshToken =
    req.cookies?.refreshToken || req.body.refreshToken;

  if (!incomingRefreshToken) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json(
        new ApiResponse(
          { reason: "Request unauthorised" },
          "Unauthorized request."
        )
      );
  }

  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
      incomingRefreshToken,
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET
    );

    let restaurant = await getNonSensitiveRestaurantInfoById(decodedToken.id);

    restaurant = restaurant[0];

    if (!restaurant) {
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json(
          new ApiResponse(
            { reason: "Token verification failed" },
            "Invalid refresh token."
          )
        );
    }

    if (incomingRefreshToken !== restaurant?.refresh_token)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json(
          new ApiResponse(
            { reason: "Tokens do not match" },
            "Unable to reinstate session."
          )
        );

    const options = {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
    };

    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(restaurant);
    const newRefreshToken = generateRefreshToken(restaurant);

    return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
      .cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, options)
      .json(
        new ApiResponse(
          {
            accessToken: accessToken,
            refreshToken: newRefreshToken,
          },
          "Session is reinitialised."
        )
      );
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json(
      new ApiResponse(
        {
          reason:
            error.message || "Error occurred while trying to refresh token",
        },
        "Unable to refresh tokens."
      )
    );
  }
});



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
